# Does the client RhoConnect database get cleared when clearing the Android app cache

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I am building an Android application using the RhoMobile framework with RhoConnect.

At present I know I can force it to delete all data by calling `Rhom::Rhom.database_full_reset_and_logout` inside the application.

I was wondering if clearing the Android App Cache (From the Android Settings Menu) clears the data stored in the Rhom Database? Or is this persisted regardless?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that clearing application data, from settings menu, is going to delete the database files with all its content.

Next time you launch your RhoMobile application, it will create new, empty databases.